# How to change interrupt handlers calling order?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I want my interrupt handler always called first, regardless when it was registered. Can I do this by standard kernel API ?

Comment: Can you clarify more about like architecture, device, etc.

Comment: I think all these things are not significant. I use request_irq() to set my interrupt handler, and I want it always called before handler of this interrupt that already installed in the system.

Comment: I understood that you are trying to reduce the interrupt latency by avoiding other ISR's execution on shared IRQ environment.

Comment: No. I need filter to catch interrupts earlier than standard system driver.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You would have to modify `request_irq()`, and recompile the entire kernel.